# Comma or no comma for restrictive clause in quotations?

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

From what I understand, clauses that restrict the subject it is modifying are not preceded by a comma.

> The dog **Charlie** has brown fur.

I am unsure about how commas interact with these clauses when the clause is quoted material.

> The line **"I love cats"** is shocking.

In the example above, "I love cats" seems restrictive. It is specifying exactly what line (out of many) that we could be referring to, similar to how "Charlie" specifies exactly what dog (out of many) that we could be referring to. I would not put a comma here. However, once I add another modifier to the subject, the sentence looks strange without a comma:

> The line that the boy wrote **"I love cats"** is shocking.

"The line that the boy wrote" now becomes the full subject, and "I love cats" is still restrictive (because the boy wrote many lines, and "I love cats" clarifies the exact line that he wrote). If I wrote it with commas (which seems more natural to me), then that suggests that "I love cats" is nonrestrictive, which it isn't.

> The line that the boy wrote, **"I love cats,"** is shocking.

Any ideas?

Comment: << and "I love cats" is still restrictive >> is incorrect. 'The line that the boy wrote', unlike 'The line', is specific, and "I love cats" adds further information rather than narrowing down further (from 1 possibility). You can't juxtapose 'The boy wrote many lines. The line that the boy wrote was "I love cats".'

Comment: For what it is worth, Grammarly didn't add a comma to The line "I love cats" is shocking.

Comment: It is tricky to look at a sentence and figure out whether a phrase is restrictive from how it changes the meaning. I suggest a better test is seeing what happens if you **remove** the phrase. Can you still identity of the subject? // What does "The line that the boy wrote is shocking" mean? You can no longer identify the line, so the phrase must be restrictive.

Comment: You're asking about integrated vs supplementary appositives? Because that's what "I love cats" is.

Comment: Ross Murray: That's the line of logic I followed as well. Should the "I love cats" clause be removed, the subject becomes vague, so the clause seems restrictive to me. In that case, would there need to be commas or not?

BillJ: I've never heard of those terms before, but I guess that's what I'm asking about, yes.